# Howto copy and text from termial to (GTK-)emacs?

Tags: emacs, clipboard

If I select text in my terminal (in my case `urxvt`) and then click with the middle mouse button into an emacs window (GTK), it pastes the selected text from terminal.

Since I don't want this behaviour for the middle mouse button I usually add this to my `.emacs` file:

```
(define-key global-map [mouse-2] nil)
```

However then I am not able to paste text from a terminal at all. So how can I fix this (for example that a selection from a terminal is inserted by `C-y`)?

This worked in my old box but since upgrading to ubuntu 13.10 and emacs24 it doesn't. So it must be possible, but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html), section [12.3.1 Using the Clipboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html):

> Prior to Emacs 24, the kill and yank commands used the primary selection, not the clipboard. If you prefer this behavior, change `x-select-enable-clipboard` to `nil`, `x-select-enable-primary` to `t`, and `mouse-drag-copy-region` to `t`. In this case, you can use the following commands to act explicitly on the clipboard: `clipboard-kill-region` kills the region and saves it to the clipboard; `clipboard-kill-ring-save` copies the region to the kill ring and saves it to the clipboard; and `clipboard-yank` yanks the contents of the clipboard at point.

The key setting you want is `x-select-enable-primary` to `t`.  You can also use a mix of the settings described there, depending on exactly what behavior you like.

Answer (score 1):

Both the variable `x-select-enable-clipboard` and function called `x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value` seem to be significant.

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)
```

Read more from this **Source** : [Integrate emacs copy paste with system copy paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216081/integrate-emacs-copy-paste-with-system-copy-paste#answer-10500056)